# Nginx reverse proxy rewrite to hide app name

Tags: nginx

This question may be asked many times, I have been reading but still can't get what I want.

I have an application running in `http://172.17.1.10:8080/myapp` I would like to setup nginx reverse proxy accessing the application using   `http://sub.domain.com` only , hidding  "myapp" in the address bar.

My current setting is:

```
server{
        listen 80;
        server_name sub.domain.com;
        location /myapp {
                rewrite ^/myapp(.*) /$1 break;
                proxy_pass http://172.17.1.10:8080;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP      $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        }

}
```

But I keep viewing the Nginx index page with `http://sub.domain.com`, and `http://sub.domain.com/myapp` the tomcat index page. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the content of the URI being processed within a location block containing a proxy_pass directive then you need to handle `Location` header rewrites with proxy_redirect :

> In some cases, the part of a request URI to be replaced cannot be determined:
>
> - When location is specified using a regular expression.
>     In this case, the directive should be specified without a URI.
> - When the URI is changed inside a proxied location using the rewrite directive, and this same configuration will be used to process a request (break).

But in your case there's no reason to use a rewrite because nginx already handles this in the proxy_pass directive while adding an URI prefix:

> If the proxy_pass directive is specified with a URI, then when a request is passed to the server, the part of a normalized request URI matching the location is replaced by a URI specified in the 
>   directive.

Also you need to remove the `proxy_redirect` directive so nginx can rewrite `Location` headers using the proxy_pass URI prefix as a pattern and the location prefix as a replacement.

So simply use this :

```
server {

    server_name sub.domain.com;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://172.17.1.10:8080/myapp/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }

}
```

Comment: I get infinite redirect loop... I think something else is redirecting it...

Comment: @Kossel Check you backend replies, it doens't come from this nginx configuration (except if your include directive imports something inappropriate).

Comment: by default the app is checked by spring Security and will redirect to /login or /home I think the further problem is not nginx related... thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change these three lines should fix you:

```
location /myapp {
            rewrite ^/myapp(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://172.17.1.10:8080;
```

To:

```
location / {
            proxy_pass http://172.17.1.10:8080/myapp;
```

Comment: I first tried that, but it just redirect to sub.domain.com/myapp, and "myapp" will still be part of url

Comment: You need to follow the redirects and find out why, my suggestion does not included redirects.  Did you remove the rewrite?

Comment: I did exactly what you mentiones, removed the  locationand the rewrite line.  now when I type sub.domain.com  it automatically redirect to  sub.domain.com/myapp   (and also with error  "myappmyapp not found" )

Comment: You could try adding a forward slash after /myapp in proxy_pass.  But it seems to me like your myapp or something else is redirecting requests.