# Nginx reverse proxy hide url

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, reverse-proxy, rewrite, url

Here is my nginx `proxy.conf` file,

```
server {
    listen port 9090;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html; # not sure whether this line is needed or not
    index index.html; # not sure whether this line is needed or not
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://google.com
    }
}
```

I'm trying to hide the original website address, example `google.com` behind my `localhost:9090`.

But when i start nginx service using this `proxy.conf` file and type `localhost:9090` in my browser it is correctly redirecting me to `google.com` but it is revealing the url `google.com` in the browser.

I saw some questions here like [How to hide backend URL/URI with Nginx reverse proxy](https://serverfault.com/questions/808166/how-to-hide-backend-url-uri-with-nginx-reverse-proxy)
, but i didn't quite get an answer to my problem.

If you need any additional information regarding this please ask in the comments. I'm ready to provide any information if that allows you to give me a solution to my problem.

Comment: Google sends this redirect. Use another backend site for your testing.

Comment: That's both true. But you can also catch the redirect with Nginx and Lua, be it for Google or another backend hanging in the same network. Detail fact: If the backend is behind a connect or socks proxy, Nginx is not able to execute the `proxy_pass` command yet.

Answer (score 1):

## Example for Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu 18.04

Backends that return hard (301) or temporary (302 or newer 303) redirects to the browser – the browser executes them – can easily take the user away from your Nginx. This can be intercepted with Lua.

What I show here is at least legally in the grey area, but rather black (regarding Google). Do not bring into production! All the security headers that Google attaches to the requests will spoil your fun anyway.

### Installation

```
# sudo apt purge nginx-*  # maybe necessary, backup your /etc/nginx/… configs before!
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable
sudo apt-cache show nginx-extras | grep -P '((xenial)|(bionic))'
sudo apt install nginx-extras  # Lua support (nginx-extras is > nginx-full)
```

### Config

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/test.conf`

```
server
{
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name niegit.com;

    # Nginx vs. Lua
    #
    # Comment: # vs. --
    # Concat: NIL vs. ..
    # $request_uri vs. ngx.var.request_uri  # path with query string
    # $is_args$args vs. ngx.var.is_args .. ngx.var.args  # query string
    # $1 vs. ngx.var[1]  # regex capturing group 1
    # $2 vs. ngx.var[2]  # regex capturing group 2

    location /
    {
        rewrite_by_lua_block
        {
            -- Probs with AJAX/XHR and/or Websockets!
            ngx.log(ngx.ALERT, 'See this text in /var/log/nginx/error.log')
            local map = {
                GET = ngx.HTTP_GET,
                POST = ngx.HTTP_POST,
            }
            ngx.req.read_body()
            local res = ngx.location.capture('/location_2' .. (ngx.var.request_uri or ''), {
               method = map[ngx.var.request_method],
               body = ngx.var.request_body
            })

            -- Detect/change redirect...
            local redirect_target = res.header.Location
            if redirect_target and res.status > 300 and res.status < 309 then
                ngx.log(ngx.ALERT, redirect_target)
                local redirect_target_changed, n, err = ngx.re.gsub(redirect_target, 'https?[:]//(?:www[.])?google[.]com(?:[:][0-9]*)?', 'http://niegit.com')
                ngx.log(ngx.ALERT, redirect_target_changed)
                return ngx.redirect(redirect_target_changed, 303)
            else
                ngx.exec('@named_location_3')
                return ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_OK)
            end
        }
    }

    location /location_2
    {
        proxy_pass https://www.google.com/;
    }

    location @named_location_3
    {
        proxy_pass https://www.google.com$request_uri;
    }
}
```

### Activate

```
cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
sudo ln -s ../sites-available/test.conf test.conf
sudo nginx -t
sudo service nginx reload  # or newer: sudo systemctl reload nginx
```

If there are no `sites-available` and `sites-enabled` folders, simply put `test.conf` in your `conf.d` folder.

### Testing

```
curl -I niegit.com  # not active at the moment
```

If you offer foreign backends under your own domain, this should only happen for test purposes or you ask the owner. The example shown here can of course be used legally for your own backends and save your ass. ;)

Comment: This does not work against website like https://uptimerobot.com which only works on https and http urls gets redirect to https. There is a public page like https://stats.uptimerobot.com/wivhjuit. My goal is to reach that without changing browser url. Any idea how that could work ?

Comment: I guess you didn't understand the line with `gsub` and can't do a regex. Also, most uptime robots query with HEAD instead of GET or POST, as I remember.